# keycloak nginx doesn't work. infinity loading of AdminUI

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, https, keycloak, bitnami

Could you help?
I'm trying to config https keycloak and grafana through nginx.
This is my nginx config file:

```
events {}

http {
    ssl_certificate /certs/my_crt.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /certs/my_key.key;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:5m;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    server 
    {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name grafana.my_domain.ru;
        location /
        {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://grafana_app:3001;
        }
    }
    
    server 
    {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name keycloak.my_domain.ru;
        location /
        {
            proxy_set_header    Host               $host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port   $server_port;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;

            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://keycloak:8080;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my docker-compose.yml file

```
docker-compose:
version: "3.7"

services:
  nginx:
    image: bitnami/nginx:1.25.3
    ports:
      - 443:443
    container_name: proxy_nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:ro
      - ./nginx/certs:/certs
    depends_on:
      - gateway
      - react
    networks:
      - custom
  keycloak:
    container_name: keycloak
    image: docker.io/bitnami/keycloak:21.0.2
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true
      - KEYCLOAK_CREATE_ADMIN_USER=true
      - KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_HOST=db_kc
      - KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_PORT=5432
      - KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_NAME=kc_postgres
      - KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_USER=postgres
      - KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_PASSWORD=postgres
      - KEYCLOAK_PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true
      - KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL=https://keycloak.my_domain.ru
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_USER=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
    depends_on:
      - db_kc
    networks:
      - custom
  grafana:
    image: bitnami/grafana:9.4.7
    container_name: grafana_app
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    environment:
      - GF_DATABASE_TYPE=postgres
      - GF_DATABASE_HOST=db_kc
      - GF_DATABASE_NAME=kc_postgres
      - GF_DATABASE_USER=postgres
      - GF_DATABASE_PASSWORD=postgres
      - KEYCLOAK_REALM=************
      - KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID=grafana
      - KEYCLOAK_SECRET=************
      - KEYCLOAK_DOMEN=keycloak.my_domain.ru
    depends_on:
      - db_kc
      - keycloak
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    volumes:
      - ./custom.ini:/etc/grafana/grafana.ini
      - grafana_data:/opt/bitnami/grafana/data
      - ./provisioning:/etc/grafana/provisioning
    networks:
      - custom
```

The error is infinity loading of Admin UI on https. If i use http with ip address and port so will be all ok.
Dev console in the browser shows me the error:

```
Refused to frame 'http://keycloak.my_domain.ru/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self'".
```

How to fix it? I was trying to search this problem in the internet (rewrite nginx config or docker-compose file) but it didn't help me yet.

I was trying this tutorial: https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/keycloak-docker-deployment-no-login-possible/7275